# Animate NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, core-animation, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

Is it possible to animate a `NSTextAttachment` in a `UITextView`?

I tried modifying its bounds but it doesn't seem to produce any effect.

```
NSAttributedString *attributedText = self.textView.attributedText;
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [attributedText attribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName atIndex:index effectiveRange:nil];
textAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    textAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);
}];
```

Is this is not possible with `NSTextAttachment`, what would you suggest doing to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: It's not clear what effect you're going for. Are you just trying to scale the text?

Comment: No, I'd like to move an image attachment around.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your question what effect you're going for? Screenshots would also be helpful if you have anything that demonstrates it.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I don't think that NSTextAttachment is animatable. It derives from NSObject so I'd assume UITextView is responsible for laying it out.  Would like to know if anyone has devised a solution for this though.